# runner.bat in the same directory as main Go package

Tags: windows, go

I was coding in GoLang, just working on personal interests, and one of my common practices is to package any commands necessary to running a program into a "runner.bat" file. This, of course, speeds up my workflow by not forcing me to type the same command(s) a thousand times. However, I noticed that when I ran my go program (a fairly simple Naive-Bayes algorithm for data processing), it would stall out. I hit ctrl + c and it threw "exit status 2". Based purely on experimentation, I discovered that if the directory had a file called "runner.bat" the go program would stall out, with no regards towards the contents of that file. If I removed my file or renamed it, everything runs just fine. My question being, why does this happen?